# Never ending recursion in Flexslider when adding a slide using addSlide

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, flexslider

I am working on a project that requires me to add a slide to the following flexslider instance

```
  $('.product_slider').flexslider({
    startAt: parseInt($('.featured_image', $(this)).data('index'), 10),
    touch: true,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    directionNav: false,
    {% if settings.product_slideshow_animation == 'none' or settings.product_slideshow_animation == 'zoom' %}
    slideshow: false,
    {% else %}
    animation: "{{ settings.product_slideshow_animation }}",
    {% endif %}
    slideshowSpeed: {% if settings.slideshow_speed != blank %}{{ settings.slideshow_speed }}{% else %}10{% endif %}*1000,
    animationSpeed: 1
  });
```

I used the following code to add a slide

```
$('.product_slider').data('flexslider').addSlide("<li>slide</li>");
```

Doing that gave me `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

So I looked into the flexslider library code and found the part of the code that's causing this problem but I am not sure how to fix it.

This is the `addSlide` function. This function never goes past the `slider.update(pos, "add")` line.

```
  slider.addSlide = function(obj, pos) {
      var $obj = $(obj);
      slider.count += 1;
      slider.last = slider.count - 1;
      console.log(slider.last);
      if (vertical && reverse) {
        (pos !== undefined) ? slider.slides.eq(slider.count - pos).after($obj) : slider.container.prepend($obj);
      } else {
        (pos !== undefined) ? slider.slides.eq(pos).before($obj) : slider.container.append($obj);
      }
      // update currentSlide, animatingTo, controlNav, and directionNav
      //THIS LINE
      slider.update(pos, "add");
      console.log("here-2");
      // update slider.slides
      slider.slides = $(slider.vars.selector + ':not(.clone)', slider);
      // re-setup the slider to accomdate new slide
      slider.setup();
      //FlexSlider: added() Callback
      slider.vars.added(slider);
    };
```

This is the `slider.update` function. This function never goes past the `methods.controlNav.update("add");` line.

```
slider.update = function(pos, action) {
  slider.doMath();

  // update currentSlide and slider.animatingTo if necessary
  if (!carousel) {
    if (pos < slider.currentSlide) {
      slider.currentSlide += 1;
    } else if (pos <= slider.currentSlide && pos !== 0) {
      slider.currentSlide -= 1;
    }
    slider.animatingTo = slider.currentSlide;
  }

  // update controlNav
  if (slider.vars.controlNav && !slider.manualControls) {
    if ((action === "add" && !carousel) || slider.pagingCount > slider.controlNav.length) {
      methods.controlNav.update("add");
    } else if ((action === "remove" && !carousel) || slider.pagingCount < slider.controlNav.length) {
      if (carousel && slider.currentSlide > slider.last) {
        slider.currentSlide -= 1;
        slider.animatingTo -= 1;
      }
      methods.controlNav.update("remove", slider.last);
    }
  }
  // update directionNav
  if (slider.vars.directionNav) { methods.directionNav.update(); }
};
```

And finally here's the methods.controlNav.update function

```
    update: function(action, pos) {
      if (slider.pagingCount > 1 && action === "add") {
        slider.controlNavScaffold.append($('<li><a href="#">' + slider.count + '</a></li>'));
      } else if (slider.pagingCount === 1) {
        slider.controlNavScaffold.find('li').remove();
      } else {
        slider.controlNav.eq(pos).closest('li').remove();
      }
      methods.controlNav.set();
      (slider.pagingCount > 1 && slider.pagingCount !== slider.controlNav.length) ? slider.update(pos, action) : methods.controlNav.active();
    }
```

I believe this function gets stuck in a recursive loop in the last line because the `slider.pagingCount` and `slider.controlNav.length` are never equal, therefore it keeps calling `slider.update` which then calls `methods.controlNav.update` which then calls `slider.update` and it's a never ending cycle

Comment: BUMP.. I am having the same issue as well.  I am using thumbnails as well in the setup.  Did you ever figure it out?